# Warn before post that includes image but no code

Tags: feature-request, questions, images

Can we have some kind of confirmation warning before posting that only includes images and not “significant” code? This may help posters include code as text and not as images

Comment: Super annoying isn't it. This and code with no indents or **excessive** indents are my biggest gripes on SO